# Merge classes in CSS modules using React, SASS and webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, css-modules

I am trying to create a simple way to override CSS classes in React components that use CSS Modules.

I can see the stringified names of the classes being imported from `styles` and being passed in via `theme`, but I can't seem to figure out how to see the actual CSS properties.

Is there a way to get access to these and merge them into a new class which can then be applied via `className`?

```
// component1.scss
.base {
  background-color: black; <-- override this property
}

// component1.js
import Component2 from './component2';
import styles from './component1.scss';

const theme = {
 base: styles.base
};

function Component1() {
 return <Component2 theme={theme} />;
}


// component2.scss
.base {
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;

  ul {
    margin: 10px;
  }
}

// component2.js
import Component2 from './component2';
import styles from './component2.scss';


function Component2({ theme }) {
 return (
    <div className={() => someFunctionThatMergesCss(styles, theme)}>
      <ul>
      ...
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```